# VB.Net Enter Key event without KeyDown or KeyPress Event

Tags: vb.net

I am using 2D barcode scanner (QR Code), and it sends around 1000-1100 characters to the textbox, and in the last, the scanner sends Enter Key.

I tried using KeyDown and KeyPress events to detect Enter key.
Problem is, it slows down the scanning speed as Keydown/Press events gets called 1000-1100 times.

Is there any better way to make it more speed efficient?

Comment: It is better you put what you tried. Barcode scanner returns enter key at the end so in key down event you just need to check ```if e.keycode = keys.enter then 'Your code here End if```

Comment: As barcode scanner writes character one by one so  keydown event will get called  every time. I tried many ways to avoid this but I also not found any solution please let us know if you find something

Comment: It may be helpful, but I only used KeyPress Event and used separate start and end for data. The data is small and the speed is ok.